# how to make swal wait for button click?

Tags: javascript, html

I am using swal("") to inform a visual message to the user after a form is submitted.

The code works however the element swal disappears instantly, if I use alert("") the code works. But the goal would be to make it work with swal("").

```js
let form = document.getElementById("form");
form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    valid = form.checkValidity();
    if(valid) {
      swal({
      title:"Registro Salvo!",
      text:"Navegue até dados de natalidade para visualizar.",
      icon:"success", 
      button:"Ok" }
      );
      return false;
    }
    else {
      return true;
    }
});
```

```html
<form id="form" action="index.html" method="POST">
  <label for="FirstName">First Name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="FirstName" placeholder="First Name" />
  <label for="LastName">Last Name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="LastName" placeholder="Last Name" />
  <input type="Submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: submitting the form causes the browser to navigate away. you could `swal({....}); return false;` in your event handler, this would cancel the submission and show the dialog, you would then need to attach an event to the OK of your dialog to re-submit the form. (or you could use ajax/fetch to submit the form)

Comment: One additional suggestion - you could change the type of your `input="Submit"` element to `button type="button"`. Then, if everything is in order with your form, you could simply call `form.submit()`. This might not be the best solution for various reasons (the user could initiate form submission from the developer console, for example), in which case you'd need server validation as well (and you should always have that).

Comment: Hi @NickSlash, I did what you mentioned and it improved the code. But the `swal({....});` is still closing automatically. I added these changes to the question. Could you tell me where I'm still doing wrong?

Comment: I used `e.preventDefault()` and my `swal{(...)}` appeared, but did not send the forms. How do I undo `e.preventDefault()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With how your code works now, your `swal` message is confirming that your form has been submitted, but not a guarantee that it has been received successfully.

If you are OK with this functionality then you can get probably get around the issue your facing by changing the submit button to a regular button and calling submit() yourself.

I've not used sweetalert (so the below code may not work, I have not tested it), but looking at the documentation you should be able to use `.then()` to capture the close/ok on your message box, so you can show the message and then actually submit the form when the user closes the message box.

```js
let button = document.getElementById("submit_button")
let form = document.getElementById("form")

button.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    swal({
        title:"Registro Salvo!",
        text:"Navegue até dados de natalidade para visualizar.",
        icon:"success", 
        button:"Ok" }
    ).then( () => {
      form.submit()
    })
})
```

```html
<form id="form" action="index.html" method="POST">
  <label for="FirstName">First Name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="FirstName" placeholder="First Name" />
  <label for="LastName">Last Name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="LastName" placeholder="Last Name" />
  <input type="button" value="Submit" id="submit_button" />
</form>
```

Comment: If the submit button is changed from `type="submit"` to `type="button"` you should not need `e.preventDefault()` as it's default action is (I think?) whatever you attach to it.